# I'm getting an error with my count inside of a while loop, C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#

I keep getting an error on my count parts, inside the while loop. I attached a screenshot so you can see my exact issue. If anyone could help me figure this out, I would be very grateful. I'm stumped!
-updated- (I updated the screenshot, so please look at that for more info!)

[image: Here is a screenshot of the error]

Code:

```
int size = 100;
String[] teams = new string [100];
String[] teamWins = new string [100] ;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string fileReader;
        StreamReader inputFile = File.OpenText("Teams.txt");
        StreamReader inputFile2 = File.OpenText("WorldSeriesWinners.txt");

        int counter = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            fileReader = inputFile.ReadLine();
            listBox1.Items.Add(fileReader);
            teams[counter] = fileReader;
            counter++;
        }

        inputFile.Close();
       
        // Populates the teamWins array
        while (!inputFile2.EndOfStream)
        {
            fileReader = inputFile2.ReadLine();
           
            teamWins[counter2] = fileReader;
            counter2++;
        }

        inputFile2.Close();
    }
      
    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
        int count = 0;
        int wins = 0;

        while (count > teamWins.Length);

        if (selectedItem == teamWins[count])
        {
            wins++;
            count++;
        }
        else
        {
            count++;
        }
}
```

Comment: the screenshot with your error doesn't seem to match your code in your question.  the code in your question references `counter2` while the screenshot shows `counter`.  Also, what is the error?

Comment: Do you know what is the error displayed?

Comment: Could you also check your `WorldSeriesWinners.txt` file and ensure that it has less than 101 lines of text?

Comment: You might consider [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Comment: I will agree with @RetiredNinja. `File.ReadAllLines` should do the work much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are mistakenly using the first counter in your 2nd loop.
Just correct to use `counter2` instead of `counter` one, or reset the first counter.
You have it correct in your code here:

```
while (!inputFile2.EndOfStream)
        {
            fileReader = inputFile2.ReadLine();
           
            teamWins[counter2] = fileReader;
            counter2++;
        }
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for looking. I actually updated the wrong picture. I'm sorry. If you look at the picture now, it will show the right one.

Comment: If you are still getting error, the error message indicates that you are trying to add a value into outside the bounds of the array (counter2[100]), so you are probably reading an additional line in the text file.